# Expection in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNItest2.helloworld()V

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I made libcc.so from my test.cpp in ubuntu, and used the instruction `ldd` to check it linking no problem with opencv2.4.2, ffmpeg0.11.1, and others.

But when I tried to use eclipse to load libcc.so, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNItest2.helloworld()V
at JNItest2.helloworld(Native Method)
at JNItest2.main(JNItest2.java:28)
```

**Java code:**

```
public class JNItest2 {
  public native void helloworld();
  static{   
      String libPath= "/home/sun/workspace/JNItest2/src";
      System.setProperty("java.library.path",libPath);
      String Path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
      System.out.println("java.library.path=" + Path);
      System.loadLibrary("cc");         
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){        
     new JNItest2().helloworld();
  }
}
```

**.h code:**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class JNItest2 */

#ifndef _Included_JNItest2
#define _Included_JNItest2
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     JNItest2
 * Method:    helloworld
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNItest2_helloworld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);    

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "JNItest2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
IplImage* image = 0; 
IplImage* prev_image = 0;
CvCapture* capture = 0;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_JNItest2_helloworld(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,int argc,char ** argv)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV,sighandler);
    int frameNum = 0;
    char* video=null;
    char* video = argv[1];
    capture = cvCreateFileCapture(video);
    if( !capture ) { 
        printf( "Could not initialize capturing..\n" );
        return ;
    }
    while(true) 
    {
        frameNum += 1;
        IplImage* frame = 0;
        int i, j, c;    

        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame )
            break;    

        if( !image ) {
            image =  cvCreateImage( cvSize(frame->width,frame->height), 8, 3);
            image->origin = frame->origin;
        }    

        cvCopy( frame, image, 0 );
        std::cerr << "The " << frameNum << "-th frame" << std::endl;
        frameNum++;
    }    

    return;
}
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But I can't solve my problem. Please help or try to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature in your `.h` file doesn't match the one in your `.cpp` file.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNItest2_helloworld(JNIEnv *, jobject);    

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNItest2_helloworld(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,int argc,char ** argv)
```

The method you're trying to call is the one from your header file. But it's missing an implementation.

If you want to pass arguments to the `C` side, you will have to declare them with your `native` methhod:

```
public native void helloworld(String[] args);
```

The resulting signature would be:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_helloworld(JNIEnv *, jobject, jobjectArray);
```

But this `String[]` is not converted into `argc` and `argv`, you will have to use the [JNI api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) to do that manually:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_helloworld(JNIEnv *env, jobject o, jobjectArray args) {
    int argc = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, args);   
    const char* argv[argc];

    // convert String[] to const char**
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        jstring string = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, args, i);
        int slength = (*env)->GetStringLength(env, string);
        const wchar_t* wchars = (*env)->GetStringChars(env, string, NULL);

        argv[i] = malloc(slength + 1); // + 1 for terminator
        wcstombs(argv[i], wchars, slength + 1);

        (*env)->ReleaseStringChars(env, string, wchars);
    }

    // use argc and argv
}
```

Comment: Tank you! I have tried it but I met another problem. The problem is that I can run on eclipse, but I can't run on cmd by runnable `jar` file.
The error message is:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at JNItest2.<clinit>(JNItest2.java:23)

Comment: @彭思倩 If you still have the absolute path to the library hardcoded in Java, I don't see why it wouldn't work, unless you moved the library.

Comment: I still set the absolute path to the library in Java, and I run the jar file in the same computer. Also, I checked the library in `/home/sun/workspace/JNItest2/src/` file. But,  when I run the jar file, the error message is still appeared.

Comment: Additional, I used the instruction `java -jar ./test5.jar ./home/sun/iDT/video/video.avi`.

Comment: @彭思倩 I can't really see the answer. But this is really a different question. If you want you can ask another question on the site, then other people can try too.

Answer (score 0):

You have this function declared:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNItest2_helloworld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

but you implement this one:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_JNItest2_helloworld(JNIEnv *env,jobject object,int argc,char ** argv)
```

Make sure to have:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_JNItest2_helloworld(JNIEnv *env,jobject object)
```

in your cpp code.